# How to set a breakpoint in function body in R-studio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have an R script which calls a function written by me. However, when I execute the script, the program doesn't stop at the debug point in the function body.
The only time debug points work is when they are set in the main script file. I am using R-studio IDE, however any general solution would also be appreciated.

Comment: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534337-Breakpoint-Troubleshooting

Comment: @rmuc8 I had seen that article before posting. It doesn't mention that function body is not a legal breakpoint. Am I missing something?

Comment: @rmuc8 There, the author is talking about functions which are defined inline and therefore Rstudio breakpoints don't work there. My issue is with the traditional function definition. Ability to stop in function body is pretty standard in other platforms like Matlab. Not sure, why there is no information available on this.

Comment: When I set a break point in a function, I can debug line by line. Since I am not familiar with Matlab, I can't draw a comparison. Do you use the latest version of Rstudio? I

Comment: @rmuc8 Does R-Studio stop at a breakpoint in a function for you if the function was called from another R script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you work on multiple files, you have to source R files with

```
debugSource("C:/Users/...")
```

instead of

```
source("C:/Users/...")
```

from your main script

Comment: could be worth noting that `debugSource` is only supported in Rstudio not in base R. So in case one considers scheduling the script later on with RScript one should switch back to `source`,..

Answer (score 1):

I 'd like to add one important point to the @rmuc8 answer.

1. Set the breakpoint in your function as the official guide says: [https://support.rstudio.com/...](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio#stopping-on-a-line). It will appear a empty or filled red circle.
2. In your main script that call that function, write above the function's invocation.

debugSource("C:/Users/...")

3. DO NOT RUN pressing CTRL+ALT+R. Run selecting and CTRL+R. Otherwise it will not stop on the breakpoint.